# How to convert IEEE-11073 16-bit SFLOAT to mantissa and exp in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, types, floating-point, ieee-11073

I want to convert two bytes to into it's mantissa and exponent and try then multiply the mantissa and exponent together to get its Int value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564270/how-to-convert-ieee-11073-16-bit-sfloat-to-simple-float-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899195/converting-two-bytes-to-an-ieee-11073-16-bit-sfloat-in-c-sharp may be helpful.

Comment: IEEE-11073 is a whole medical device communications protocol. Please point to the specific subsection that proscribes how your floats are formatted.