# Interpreting Bluetooth BLE Data from Flutter App: Understanding Systolic Pressure Values

Tags: android, flutter, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy, device

I connected my device with Bluetooth BLE using a Flutter application, and this is what I obtained: 'indication received from 00002a35-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, value :(0x) DE-F6-F4-16-F3-FF-07-E4-07-01-14-08-2B-00-B2-F2-01-80-00'. How do I interpret these results? When I used nRF Connect, the interpreted values of systolic pressure are: 127.0 mmHg. How was the systolic value obtained? Considering that the format of the systolic pressure is sfloat (2 bytes) and 'The value of 1 equals 1.0 mmHg. The valid range is 0-300.' However, I was unable to determine how the systolic and diastolic values were obtained in mmHg. How can I demonstrate that it is equal to 127.0 mmHg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GATT Specification Supplement](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gss/) documents the definitions for all GATT characteristics. I your case you will find the information for Blood Pressure Measurement on [page 43](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/gatt-specification-supplement/GATT_Specification_Supplement.pdf#page=43) of GATT Specification
Supplement, Version Date: 2024-02-21

With regard to the Flags field, the Blood Pressure Measurement Compound Value - Systolic in `mmHg` is found in byte 1 and 2 as `medfloat16`.

`medfloat16` is an IEEE-11073 16-bit SFLOAT value. You can find lots of information on Stack Overflow about how to convert it to a float value in your preferred programming language. Examples:

[How to convert IEEE-11073 16-bit SFLOAT to simple float in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564270/how-to-convert-ieee-11073-16-bit-sfloat-to-simple-float-in-java)

[Converting two bytes to an IEEE-11073 16-bit SFLOAT in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899195/converting-two-bytes-to-an-ieee-11073-16-bit-sfloat-in-c-sharp)

For your measurement 0xF4F6, the mantissa value is 1270 and the exponent value is -1.

Addition, SFLOAT (16-bit) representation:

Bits 0-11  represent the `mantissa`, Bits 12-15 represent the `exponent`

`mantissa`: 0x04F6 -> 2's complement -> 1270
`exponent`: 0x000F -> 2's complement -> -1

Comment: How did you calculate that the mantissa value of 0xF6F4 is 1270 and the exponent value is -1 please

Comment: What part of the IEEE-11073 SFLOAT conversion examples didn't you understand?