# Bluetooth Low Energy Glucose GATT profile measurement parsing value

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I want to parse the GATT characteristic org.bluetooth.characteristic.glucose_measurement (0x2A18) with Java/Android. More details here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.glucose_measurement.xml

all worked so far, starting with

```
byte[] values = characteristic.getValue();
```

then according to the description above i parsed the values:

```
boolean timeOffsetPresent = (values[0] & 0x01) > 0;
boolean typeAndLocationPresent = (values[0] & 0x02) > 0;
String concentrationUnit = (values[0] & 0x04) > 0 ? "mol/L" : "kg/L";
boolean sensorStatusAnnunciationPresent = (values[0] & 0x08) > 0;
boolean contextInfoFollows = (values[0] & 0x10) > 0;

long seqNum = (long) (values[1] & 255);
seqNum |= (long) (values[2] & 255) << 8;

int glucose = values[10] & 255;
glucose |= (values[11] & 255) << 8;

int year = values[3] & 255;
year |= (values[4] & 255) << 8;
byte month = values[5];
byte day = values[6];
byte hour = values[7];
byte min = values[8];
byte sec = values[9];
```

All values are correct, except the glucose value. I received concentrationUnit=kg/L so the value was sent according to "Glucose Concentration - units of kg/L" from the documentation. Unfortunately the test value is

```
System.out.println("glucose: "+glucose); // equals 28336
```

28336 is total wrong, as the value should be 110 mg/dl.

Any suggestions what is wrong here and how I can fix this? Strange thing is that all other values are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked states that the concentration is an `SFLOAT`, which should be an "IEEE-11073 16-bit SFLOAT".
[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564270/how-to-convert-ieee-11073-16-bit-sfloat-to-simple-float-in-java) tells you how to decode such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for this important hint! I even found a very neat solution using the Android API: `characteristic.getFloatValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SFLOAT, offset);` where the offset states the starting position of the related bytes within the complete byte array result