# How to convert or transcode BLE of IEEE 11073-10404 (Pulse Oximeter) to get SPO2

Tags: python, floating-point, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm working on creating a PHG(personal health gateway) using `PRi` that written with Python to detect PHD(personal home device) such as Pulse Oximeter, Blood pleasure etc.

For Pulse Oximeter I've read about IEEE standard `IEEE 11073-10404` and GATT definition. I've found a data contained into characteristics at `2A5F` and dig into service number at `1822` then I've got data `1fc0f34f 00c0f34f 00c0f350 00000100 0100a2e4`

Definition document https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.plx_continuous_measurement.xml inside the link it define where the data containing on a stream

I've searched in stack-overflow a bit, I found some question about `SFLOAT` but I don't understand why there are don't have build-in function to convert it. I'm not sure if python has method to convert `SFLOAT` or instead, I must implement it

Another question, the data I've got it can be use for transcode into SPO2 value? or I must mapping into x72 (Bluetooth classic attribute) then transcode into SPO2 value

Comment: You have to write your own method in python to translate the binary into a float.  Here's a similar question with some details on SFLOAT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564270/how-to-convert-ieee-11073-16-bit-sfloat-to-simple-float-in-java

Comment: @TimTisdall Thank you, I don't understand about why they use hex with bit operator a lot such as 0x0F, 0x0800 . Can you explain ?

Comment: I don't think many languages have a binary notation so they use hex. `value & 0x08` means doing a bit-wise `AND` and are trying to look at the 4th least significant bit while ignoring the rest. `value & 0x08` will be a non-zero value if and only if the 4th bit is 1.