# How to decode pulse oximeter output into readable

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im trying to decode data from pulse oximeter device using the nrf Connect App.

From the Pulse Oximeter(0X1822).  PLX Spot-Check Measurement service I got the below response:

SPOT MEASUREMENT:

(0x) 17-61-00-60-00-E1-07-01-01-01-22-13-20-00-20-00-00

CONTINOUS MEASUREMENT:
(0x) 0c-62-00-4E-00-20-00-00-00-00

PROFILE SAYS its SFLOAT value, But I'm stuck to converting this to readable value.

Expected value: Spo2 and heart rate from the above response

I also looked in the pulse oximeter profile in the Bluetooth page but it seems confusing

Profile [image: Service]

NRF CONNECT APP SCREENSHOT:

[image: nrf Connect App screenshot:]

pulse oximeter details:http://www.choicemmed.eu/product_center/253

Please help me to get readable data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert IEEE-11073 16-bit SFLOAT to simple float in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14707658/8124605)

Comment: its doesn't helps @Risto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page helps me lot: https://thejeshgn.com/2020/08/05/reverse-engineering-a-bluetooth-low-energy-oximeter/

From this Spot check value :17-61-00-60-00-E1-07-01-01-01-22-13-20-00-20-00-00

Byte[1] refers to spo2 rate

Byte[3] refers to pulse rate

```
int spo2 = packet[1]; 
int pulseRate = packet[3] | ((packet[2] & 64) << 1);

System.out.println(spo2);
System.out.println(pulseRate);
```

**Spo2:97
pulse rate:98**

This scenarios is same for continuous check value:(0x) 0c-**62**-00-**4E**-00-20-00-00-00-00

To convert hex code value into int in dart

```
int val=0X62;
print(val);
```